# MySQL: Creating a table that with a foreign key that references a primary key made up of foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table of books, which stores book IDs and titles, authors, etc., a table of customers which has customer IDs (PK), customer name, birthday. Then there is a table of transactions, which includes the BookId and the CustomerID as foreign keys. The primary key of this transaction table is the two foreign key columns.

The problem is now I am creating a table of book ratings based on transactions which have occurred (So a customer can't rate a book they don't own, or the same book twice.). This table must contain the bookID, the customerID, and the rating info. I'm trying to constrain the table so that each bookID and customerID row must reference an existing row in the transaction table. However, none of the constraints I've tried so far work. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my tables at the moment:

```
CREATE TABLE eBook
 (      BookTitle   VARCHAR(50),
    BookID      CHAR(13) NOT NULL,
    BookPub     CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    BookDate    DATE NOT NULL,
    BookHard    BOOL NOT NULL,
    BookSize    INT NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT PKBookID PRIMARY KEY (BookID)
);

CREATE TABLE customer
(       CustID      CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    CustSSN     CHAR(11) NULL,
    CustName    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CustBirth   INT(4) NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT PKCustID PRIMARY KEY (CustID),
CONSTRAINT UniqSSN UNIQUE (CustSSN)
);

CREATE TABLE Buys
(   BuysID      CHAR(5) NOT NULL                    
BookID      CHAR(13) NOT NULL,
CustID      CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
TransDate   DATETIME NOT NULL,
Price       DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK1 FOREIGN KEY (BookID) REFERENCES eBook (BookID)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT FK2 FOREIGN KEY (CustID) REFERENCES customer (CustID)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT PKBuys PRIMARY KEY (BookID, CustID)
);

CREATE TABLE Rating
(   BookID      CHAR(13) NOT NULL,
CustID      CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
RatingID    CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
Rating      INT(1) NOT NULL,
RatingDate  DATE NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK13 FOREIGN KEY (BookID, CustID) REFERENCES buys (BookID, CustID)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT PKRating PRIMARY KEY (RatingID)
);
```

Comment: Don't forget to add to your question what you have tried(as in the actual create table or query or whatever it may be) so people can easily help you.

Comment: Though some would argue this is not the most correct way, but what I would do instead is to just add the rating column to the Buys table. That way a user can rate the buy or not, but they can only rate their own purchase.

Comment: It would probably be better to have an auto-increment ID as the primary key in the `Buys` table, and use that as the foreign key in the `Rating` table. You can still have a unique key on `(BookID, CustID)` to prevent duplicate purchases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a foreign key on your `Rating` table that should constrain `Rating` rows each to correspond to a `Buys` row.  I suppose that the problem must be with your other objective, that customers cannot rate the same book twice.  With respect to that, I guess you have a misconception about foreign keys: they have to be unique on the *target* table, but they do not automatically have to be unique on the referring side.

To prevent multiple `Rating` rows having the same combination of `BookID` and `CustomerID`, you need an additional `UNIQUE` constraint on the `Rating` table, naming those columns.  Alternatively, you could give the `Rating` table a composite primary key consisting of those columns.  Either way, you'll have separate constraints, one establishing the uniqueness of those columns in the referring table, and the other constraining them to pairs that appear in the `Buys` table.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a multi column foreign key reference as documented on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html
That should do the trick.

Your sample code contains an error. You are missing a (,) in the Buys table.

```
CREATE TABLE eBook
 (      BookTitle   VARCHAR(50),
    BookID      CHAR(13) NOT NULL,
    BookPub     CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    BookDate    DATE NOT NULL,
    BookHard    BOOL NOT NULL,
    BookSize    INT NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT PKBookID PRIMARY KEY (BookID)
);

CREATE TABLE customer
(       CustID      CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    CustSSN     CHAR(11) NULL,
    CustName    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CustBirth   INT(4) NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT PKCustID PRIMARY KEY (CustID),
CONSTRAINT UniqSSN UNIQUE (CustSSN)
);

CREATE TABLE Buys
(   BuysID      CHAR(5) NOT NULL,                   
BookID      CHAR(13) NOT NULL,
CustID      CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
TransDate   DATETIME NOT NULL,
Price       DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK1 FOREIGN KEY (BookID) REFERENCES eBook (BookID)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT FK2 FOREIGN KEY (CustID) REFERENCES customer (CustID)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT PKBuys PRIMARY KEY (BookID, CustID)
);

CREATE TABLE Rating
(   BookID      CHAR(13) NOT NULL,
CustID      CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
Rating      INT(1) NOT NULL,
RatingDate  DATE NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK13 FOREIGN KEY (BookID, CustID) REFERENCES buys (BookID, CustID)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT PKRating PRIMARY KEY (BookID, CustID)
);
```

When using this corrected ddl, the tables are created just fine.

I've created some test data

```
insert into `ebook`(`BookTitle`,`BookID`,`BookPub`,`BookDate`,`BookHard`,`BookSize`) values ('grey','1','ME','2015-02-06',1,10);
insert into `customer`(`CustID`,`CustSSN`,`CustName`,`CustBirth`) values ('1','daCust','Cust',1974);
insert into `buys`(`BuysID`,`BookID`,`CustID`,`TransDate`,`Price`) values ('1','1','1','2015-02-06 00:00:00',10.00);
insert into `rating`(`BookID`,`CustID`,`RatingID`,`Rating`,`RatingDate`) values ('1','1','1',1,'2015-02-06');
```

Now adding the following data will result in an error due to the foreign key constraint.

```
insert into `rating`(`BookID`,`CustID`,`RatingID`,`Rating`,`RatingDate`) values ('7','3','1',1,'2015-02-06');
```

To ensure that the user can add only one rating per book you should add a unique constraint on the fields BookID and CustID or set those fields as primary key. In the working code example above i have added those fields as primary key and removed the obsolete RatingID.

Comment: Please include relevant information from the resource in your answer. Link-only answers can become stale.

Comment: Thanks, I did try that on the ratings table, but for some reason it isn't constrained properly.